# Maven: Spring Boot Application Not Starting With Sub-Modules in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

I am facing an issue when starting my Spring Boot application with sub-modules in IntelliJ IDEA. Before creating sub-modules, I didn't encounter this problem.

My project structure is as follows:

- parentModule
- - serverModule

I want to run the serverModule, which has the @SpringBootApplication main method and a REST controller. When I try to run the application from within IntelliJ IDEA, it hits the main method but then immediately shuts down with "Process finished with exit code 0".

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Checking the project configuration and dependencies in IntelliJ IDEA. Everything seems to be set up correctly.

However, when I try to run the application from within IntelliJ IDEA, I get an error. Specifically, the application fails to start with the following message:

[image]

I have tried adding the spring-boot-starter-web dependency since I am able to run the application without any issues when not using a sub-module structure.

Here is POM.xml for my parent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.boot.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>my engine maven</description>
    <modules>
        <module>serve</module>
    </modules>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and here is the POM.xml for child(server) module

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.boot.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>serve</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I'm not sure what's causing this error or how to fix it. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add start-class with value of your Application class path with whole package in your parent pom,
for example, your sever class's name is ServerApplication, in package com.example, then add below property in your parent pom's

```
<properties>
    <start-class>com.example.ServerApplication</start-class>
</properties>
```

Comment: It was a simple fix that I couldn't figure out on my own, and it worked like a charm. Thank you :)